# MySQL cumulative sum order by date

Tags: mysql

I am executing a cumulative sum order by date and I do not get the expected result. Some records are presented in a different order compared to the order used for the sum.

[Please have a look at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7204d4/1)

I would expect either the following result:

*2015-05-05T00:00:00Z 50 30 20 <strike>90</strike> **120***

2015-05-05T00:00:00Z 60 30 30 <strike>120</strike> **100**

2015-05-04T00:00:00Z 70 50 20 <strike>30</strike> **70**

2015-05-04T00:00:00Z 80 40 40 <strike>70</strike> **50**

2015-05-03T00:00:00Z 30 20 10 10

or the following order:

***2015-05-05T00:00:00Z 60 30 30 120***

2015-05-05T00:00:00Z 50 30 20 90

<strike>2015-05-05T00:00:00Z 60 30 30 120</strike>

**2015-05-04T00:00:00Z 80 40 40 70**

2015-05-04T00:00:00Z 70 50 20 30

<strike>2015-05-04T00:00:00Z 80 40 40 70</strike>

2015-05-03T00:00:00Z 30 20 10 10

(Added) please note that negative values are also possible. This is the reason why I have mentioned on answers below that an order on the cumulative sum would not solve the problem. As an example I will modify slightly the result:

*2015-05-05T00:00:00Z **30 60 -30 60***

2015-05-05T00:00:00Z 50 30 20 90

2015-05-04T00:00:00Z 80 40 40 70

2015-05-04T00:00:00Z 70 50 20 30

2015-05-03T00:00:00Z 30 20 10 10

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your data isn't actually orderable because there is nothing unique about the dates and times.

Comment: I agree, there are rows with the same date. But, what I find surprising, is that the order used for printing the result (rows with date 2015-05-04) is not the order used to make the cumulative sum (last column is the cumulative sum of the adjacent column).

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7204d4/2
gives your expceted output.. I have added @cum := @cum + tot_earn_pts - tot_redeem_pts asc after your query.

Comment: This is not solving the problem. It has change the order of the rows but the last column of each row is not the cumulative sum of the adjacent row.

Answer (score 0):

**Add extra fields in order by "cum_liability_pts" desc:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7204d4/8)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT date,
           tot_earn_pts,
           tot_redeem_pts,
           tot_earn_pts - tot_redeem_pts AS tot_liability_pts,
           @cum := @cum + tot_earn_pts - tot_redeem_pts AS cum_liability_pts
      FROM (   
        SELECT date, 
               earn_points AS tot_earn_pts, 
               redeem_points AS tot_redeem_pts
          FROM i_report_total_order
       /* WHERE website_id = 36 */

           ) tots
      JOIN (SELECT @cum := 0) init
  ORDER BY date asc 
       ) res_asc
ORDER BY date desc, cum_liability_pts desc;
```

Comment: This would not solve the problem if the cumulative sum decreases due to a negative value.

Comment: Are you remove row where cumulative sum is negative ?

Comment: I will add above a possible scenario for negative values.